# Contradiction between complete.casses and which and is.na that I do not understand

Tags: r

I use a simple example from dataset "airquality".

The first four rows are complete which can be checked simply with complete.cases

Row 5 contains missing values.
Row 6 also contains missing values.

This can be checked quickly by:

```
is.na(airquality[5,])
is.na(airquality[6,])
```

I would expect that `which(is.na(airquality))` would give me the list of row numbers that include at least one true statement, i.e. at least one `NA` value.

However, it lists 5, 10, 25 ... , i.e. row number 6 is NOT listed. Why? there is a `NA` value in row number 6!

```
library(datasets)
complete.cases(airquality)
is.na(airquality[5,])
is.na(airquality[6,])
which(is.na(airquality))
```

There is obviously something that I do not understand here.

Answer (score 2):

From `help("is.na")`:

> The data frame method for is.na returns a logical matrix with the same
>   dimensions as the data frame, and with dimnames taken from the row and
>   column names of the data frame.

In other words, it's not giving you the information you're assuming it's giving you. It's giving you the elements of the matrix described above, by counting going down the columns. Try

```
# get the cases with missingness
which(!complete.cases(airquality))

 [1]   5   6  10  11  25  26  27  32  33  34  35  36  37  39  42  43  45  46  52
[20]  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  65  72  75  83  84  96  97  98 102 103
[39] 107 115 119 150

# and check against is.na
unique(sort(which(is.na(airquality), arr.ind = TRUE)[ , 1]))

 [1]   5   6  10  11  25  26  27  32  33  34  35  36  37  39  42  43  45  46  52
[20]  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  65  72  75  83  84  96  97  98 102 103
[39] 107 115 119 150

all.equal(which(!complete.cases(airquality)),
          unique(sort(which(is.na(airquality), arr.ind = TRUE)[ , 1])))

TRUE
```

Comment: Sometime the obvious just does not get into my mind. Of course, !complete.case will give me what I want. Nevertheless, I think newbees as myself are a bit puzzled by the output of  which(is.na(airquality), arr.ind = F) when they just do which(is.na(airquality))

Comment: @Oliver Yeah, in a sense, `which(is.na())` in this case just gives you *more* information than `!complete.cases()`. You get whether each row has some `NA` value from `!complete.cases()`, but you get whether each individual element is `NA` from `which(is.na())`.  There's a lot of weird things that can trip you up like that with R, although to be fair, that's true of any (human or programming) language.